# Rounding from math.h incorrect

Tags: c++

I'm using the tasks on code abbey to work my way through C++.
I'm trying to use the rounding function by importing math.h and it works for every value that I'm trying to input apart from one pair
when I divide 4991264 by 4 and round it, it outputs the answer as 1.24782e+06

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int getTotal(){
int total;
cin >> total;
return total;
}

void doMath(int total){
    int count;
    double holder;
    double holder2;
    double solution;
    solution = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (count != total){
        cout << "enter a number ";
        cin >> holder;
        cout << "enter a number ";
        cin >> holder2;
        solution = (holder / holder2);
        cout << round(solution) << "\n";
        ++count;
}

}
int main(){

int total = getTotal();
doMath(total);


return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/f40E1s is the code and the inputs.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you see has "extrange" or "bad" in the output you obtained?

Comment: That looks like the right answer to me.

Comment: My `cout` skills are a tad rusty, but don't you need to specify that you want more digits of precision in the formatted value if you want more digits of precision in the formatted value?

Comment: The website I'm using is expecting the answer of 1247816 and all my other inputs automatically format to the nearest whole number while using round

Comment: The arithmetic is correct, you just aren't printing it right

Comment: Incidentally, you're not using math.h/cmath here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A floating point variable keeps a value of a given type (in memory).
This value "rests" there with its own precision, in binary format.
When this value has to be shown or **output** in someway, typically is converted to decimal format. This conversion can have loss of precision sometimes.

Anyway, when you are doing precise arithmetica operations, as in your example, the conversion to decimal is not, in general, an issue.
What it has to be understood here is that "printing" a value is not the same that "showing the exact value held in memory".

The object `cout` has predefined ways to show the values you are computing.
The exact value has not changed, **it's not, in this case, a problem of bad computing**.
Indeed, **it's only a matter of how to show this value on screen**.

The format used to print the value is: *in exponential notation with "only" 6 decimal digits precision*.

You need to increase the precision of values when printed, and to avoid exponential notation.

Take a look to this website:  [Output formatting in C++](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html)

Thus, for example, the following code do the job (for a precision of 8 decimal digits):

```
  cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(8) << round(solution) << "\n";
```

In general, you have to investigate and practice more about this formatting options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I used:
   `cout << (int)round(solution) << "\n";`
My only wonder is why was this the only one that didn't automatically round to an integer but my other 15 inputs did?

Comment: @jarkia You don't understand the problem, and you've selected the wrong solution (`cout << (int)round(solution)` is not the solution). We can help you but you need to listen to the advice.

Comment: @jarkia: Your other inputs would have corresponded to values having 6 decimal digits precision of less. The value you show in your question has 8 decimal digits precision. So, the standard behaviour is to show only the first 6 decimal digits precision and by means of exponential notation. Again, it's an output formatting issue. Please, investigate more about the way in that `cout` shows **floating point values** and how can you choose the several different ways in that the same value is shown.